# use functions in php-isset with ternary operator

Tags: php, function, ternary-operator

Simple stuff,

This works without any problems:

```
$openMonday =  rtrim(chunk_split($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'], 2, ':'), ':');
$business->openingTimes['monday']       = isset($openMonday) ? $result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'] : '';
```

But I don't want to write two lines for this because then I would have to do it also for all the other opening hours.

Why can't I just write

```
$business->openingTimes['monday']       = isset(rtrim(chunk_split($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'], 2, ':'), ':')) ? $result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'] : '';
```

I'm always getting the error that it's expecting a variable. How can I use methods in the isset with ternary operator?

Comment: If you need to do the same for all the other opening hours, you should try to make a function of it! So that you could write it in two lines, and be more concise when you call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem  here is that `isset()` is not a real function but a language construct, which requires its arguments to be variables, or it issues a syntax error.

See also the manual entry: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Anyway, as also @deceze said, you probably do not want to use `isset()` here, since it is used to check if a variable exists.

In this case, you could use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), so instead of writing

```
$openMonday =  rtrim(chunk_split($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'], 2, ':'), ':');
$business->openingTimes['monday'] = isset($openMonday) ? $result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'] : '';
```

you could do

```
$openMonday =  rtrim(chunk_split($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'], 2, ':'), ':');
$business->openingTimes['monday'] = !empty($openMonday) ? $result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'] : '';
```

And you should not worry to make it a one-liner at any cost! Create a function instead, and then call it when needed... But if you really still want to do it inline, then you could do

```
$business->openingTimes['monday'] = !empty(rtrim(chunk_split($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'], 2, ':'), ':')) ? $result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'] : '';
```

just remember that the above requires at least **PHP 5.5**!

And finally, the row above could just be written as

```
$business->openingTimes['monday'] = !rtrim(chunk_split($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'], 2, ':'), ':') ? $result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'] : '';
```

without any need for `isset()` nor `empty()`

Comment: Why the downvote? This answers OP question! The fact that s/he shouldn't use `isset()` in this case is another matter...

Comment: If the OP is going off into a completely wrong direction you find it more useful to advise him to update his PHP version instead of pointing out that he's going into the wrong direction?

Comment: @deceze That, IMHO, is another matter, but this answer is not wrong per-se: he asked why isset() fails, and I told him.

Comment: @deceze added a better example which does not use isset() and explains why it is wrong, as you did.

Comment: And why is `empty` preferable here?

Comment: @deceze Because the OP seems to be actually using `isset()` as a mean to check if a variable is not empty, that is, has a "truth-y" value.

Comment: `empty` has the same restriction on passing non-variables as `isset`. And you need neither, since you are working with defined variables/values, as I stated in my answer. A simple `$var == true` or just `$var` does exactly the same thing here.

Comment: @deceze you are right, and I wrote about the restriction in my answer. Anyway, I personally prefer to use the `empty()` check instead of relying on automatic conversion to boolean, it looks clearer to me to write `if(!empty($var)) { ... }` instead of `if($var) { ... }`

Comment: May I please refer you to [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) for why that's bad practice?

Comment: @well that's not a Bible, is it? Though I do appreciate the suggestion, and updated my answer.

Comment: Nope, not a bible. But hopefully a useful explanation what `isset` and `empty` are for and what they're not for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `isset` here! `isset` is used to safely test whether... well... *a variable exists.* You *know* your variable exists, because you're declaring it on the line before. If you want to mush it into one line, you're not even using a variable, you're directly working with the *value*. You just want to compare the value to `false`, which you can do inline easily.

Just get rid of `isset`. And read [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: I understand your point, but that still wouldn't answer my questions on how do I write all of the code in just one line except in two by using a function inside the isset. 

Because, I don't know if the opening_hours are given so I want to do it like that :

`isset($result['opening_hours']['periods'][2]['open']['time']) ? $result['opening_hours']['periods'][2]['open']['time'] : '';`

But, I'm getting the numbers in this format `0000` and need to transform it to 00:00 - That's why I'm asking. The above was just an example how it would work but how I don't want it to work.

Comment: Please give a clear example of what your data looks like or may look like and what you expect the result to be. It's hard to suggest appropriate code to handle your data if all we have to go on is an overly complicated bad code sample.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

```
    $business->openingTimes['monday']       = isset($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time']) ? rtrim(chunk_split($result['opening_hours']['periods'][1]['open']['time'], 2, ':'), ':') : '';
```

To explain what I did. I asked if the variable is set, and if so it uses the method chunk_split otherwise the string will be empty.